# @InjectMocks on a class that has primitives as fields

Tags: java, mockito

Here's my class I'm trying to mock.

```
private MemcachedClient memcachedClient;

private CachedObjectFactory cachedObjectFactory;

private int cacheTimeToLive;

private boolean hasCert;

@Autowired
public MyClass(CachedObjectFactory cachedObjectFactory,
                         MemcachedClient memcachedClient,
                         @Value("${cache.ttl.in.second}") int cacheTimeToLive,
                         @Value("${hasCert}") boolean hasCert) {
    this.cachedObjectFactory = cachedObjectFactory;
    this.memcachedClient = memcachedClient;
    this.cacheTimeToLive = cacheTimeToLive;
    this.hasCert = hasCert;
}
```

When I use `@InjectMocks`, it complains that it can't figure out how to initialize it with a default constructor (because there isn't one).  I think mockito could use create this, but I don't know how to inject a primitive (the boolean/cacheTimeToLive).  Is there a way to do this in my test?

Comment: How about initializing the class in a @Before method in your tests? 
`myClass = new MyClass(mockedCachedObjectFactory, mockedMemcachedClient, intValue, boolValue)`?

Comment: Just to be clear: you're not trying to mock that class, you're trying to inject mocks into its fields?

Comment: +1 to dur; InjectMocks can lure you into a false sense of security, as it will inject `null` or [fall through to other types of injection](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) silently. It'd be much safer and cleaner to explicitly call your constructor from your test.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis correct

Comment: @dur that link seems old.  I also don't see where it answers my question.  This is a better link: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html  FWIW, I did look at this before I asked my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Mockito documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html):

> 1. **Constructor injection**; the biggest constructor is chosen, then arguments are resolved with mocks declared in the test only. If the object is successfully created with the constructor, then **Mockito won't try the other strategies**. Mockito has decided to no corrupt an object if it has a parametered constructor.
>      Note: If arguments can not be found, then null is passed. If non-mockable types are wanted, then constructor injection won't happen. In these cases, you will have to satisfy dependencies yourself.
>
> [...]
>
> And finally, no injection will happen on the type in this case:
>
> ```
> public class ArticleManager {
>     private ArticleDatabase database;
>     private ArticleCalculator calculator;
>
>     ArticleManager(ArticleObserver observer, boolean flag) {
>         // observer is not declared in the test above.
>         // flag is not mockable anyway
>     }
> }
> ```

You will have to satisfy dependencies yourself, for example with a setup method using JUnit's [`@Before`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html).